# Calling built-in function in cell on a time trigger (Google Spreadsheets Script)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets as a "middleman" to fetch and hold values from an RSS Feed. Using =ImportFeed, when the sheet is opened, the values from the RSS feed are updated in the sheet. This inserts values into cells A1:E1.

```
sheet1, cell A1 contains:
=ImportFeed("http://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed", "items" , FALSE, 1)
```

But in my setup there won't be a user actively opening the sheet. Rather I need this function to run on a timer, e.g. every hour. I tried the following in the sheet's Script Editor but of course it won't run.

```
function fetchRSS() {
  var response = 
    ImportFeed("https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss", "items" , FALSE, 1);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue([response]);
}
```

Ideally the above function could be called with everyHours(n) or via the UI Trigger method.

Comment: If no one is opening the sheet, there is no `ActiveSheet` to get.  Try another method (`getSheetByName` is my favorite).

Comment: @Ron Kloberdanz The script is the container-bound script of Spreadsheet, and when the script with ``var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()`` is run by the time-driven triggers, ``sheet`` becomes the first sheet of the Spreadsheet. Of course, if users want to use the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet, it is required to use the method of ``getSheetByName()``.

Comment: @Tanaike, good point that I did not know.  Thx

Answer (score 2):

- You want to achieve `=IMPORTFEED("https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss", "items" , FALSE, 1)` using Google Apps Script.
- You want to put the retrieved values to a sheet in the active spreadsheet.

If my understanding for your question is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- There is not method of `ImportFeed()` in Google Apps Script.

  - In order to achieve `=IMPORTFEED()`, I used the following flow.

    1. Retrieve values from `https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss` using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`.
    2. Parse the retrieved values using `XmlService.parse()`.
    3. Put the values to Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When you use this script, please copy and paste the following script to your script editor, and run `fetchRSS()`.

```
// In the case of this function, if "n" is 1, the 1st item is retrieved.
function ImportFeed(url, n) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(res);
  var item = xml.getRootElement().getChild("channel").getChildren("item")[n - 1].getChildren();
  var values = item.reduce(function(obj, e) {
    obj[e.getName()] = e.getValue();
    return obj;
  }, {});
  return [[values.title, values.link, values.pubDate, values.description]];
}

// Please run this function.
function fetchRSS() {
  var response = ImportFeed("https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss", 1);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, response.length, response[0].length).setValues(response);
}
```

#### Note:

- This script supposes that you use the container-bound script of Spreadsheet.
- When you run `fetchRSS()` using the time trigger, the values are written the last row of the first sheet of the Spreadsheet. If you want to put the values to the specific sheet in the Spreadsheet, please modify from `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` to `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(name)`.
- In this modified script, if you want to use other URL, when the structure of xml and the names of child element-node are different from `https://www.nasa.gov/rss/dyn/breaking_news.rss`, it is required to modify `ImportFeed()`.

#### References:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [XmlService.parse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/xml-service#parsexml)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks @tanaike, this works pretty close to what I needed. The issue is the " return [[values.title, values.link..." array that is 'hard-coded'; this would be problematic as I would be using RSS feeds from different sources, and not all of them have the same objects being returned. Could this array be replaced with a for loop easily?

Comment: @Jake I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. You want to use the script for various URLs. If my understanding is correct, this script can use RSS 2.0. For example, when URL is modified to ``http://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed``, the values can be retrieved. If this was not what you want, can I ask you about the detail of what you want? And, I cannot understand about ``Could this array be replaced with a for loop easily?``. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.