# Parse XML Feed via Google Apps Script (Cannot read property 'getChildren' of undefined")

Tags: parsing, google-apps-script, rss

I need to parse a Google Alert RSS Feed with Google Apps Script.
[Google Alerts RSS-Feed](https://www.google.de/alerts/feeds/06807031914929345698/10604166159629661594)

I found [a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52395618/10595326) which should do the job but I cant get it working with Google's RSS Feed:

The [feed](https://www.google.de/alerts/feeds/06807031914929345698/10604166159629661594) looks like this:

```
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:idx="urn:atom-extension:indexing">
<id>tag:google.com,2005:reader/user/06807031914929345698/state/com.google/alerts/10604166159629661594</id>
<title>Google Alert – garbe industrial real estate</title>
<link href="https://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/06807031914929345698/10604166159629661594" rel="self"/>
<updated>2022-03-17T19:34:28Z</updated>
<entry>
<id>tag:google.com,2013:googlealerts/feed:10523743457612307958</id>
<title type="html"><b>Garbe Industrial</b> plant Multi-User-Immobilie in Ludwigsfelde - <b>Property</b> Magazine</title>
<link href="https://www.google.com/url?rct=j&sa=t&url=https://www.property-magazine.de/garbe-industrial-plant-multi-user-immobilie-in-ludwigsfelde-117551.html&ct=ga&cd=CAIyGWRmNjU0ZGNkMzJiZTRkOWY6ZGU6ZGU6REU&usg=AFQjCNENveXYlfrPc7pZTltgXY8lEAPe4A"/>
<published>2022-03-17T19:34:28Z</published>
<updated>2022-03-17T19:34:28Z</updated>
<content type="html">Die <b>Garbe Industrial Real Estate</b> GmbH startet ihr drittes Neubauprojekt in der Metropolregion Berlin/Brandenburg. Der Projektentwickler hat sich&nbsp;...</content>
<author>

...
</feed>
```

I want to extract entry -> id, title, link, updated, content.

I used this script:

```
function ImportFeed(url, n) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var xml = XmlService.parse(res);

  //var item = xml.getRootElement().getChild("channel").getChildren("item")[n - 1].getChildren();
  var item = xml.getRootElement().getChildren("entry")[n - 1].getChildren();

  var values = item.reduce(function(obj, e) {

    obj[e.getName()] = e.getValue();
    return obj;
    }, {});
  
  return [[values.id, values.title, values.link, values.updated, values.content]];  
}
```

I modified this part, but all i got was "TypeError: Cannot read property 'getChildren' of undefined"

```
//var item = xml.getRootElement().getChild("channel").getChildren("item")[n - 1].getChildren();
  var item = xml.getRootElement().getChildren("entry")[n - 1].getChildren();
```

Any idea is welcome!

Comment: Have you tried to replace "feed" with "rss"?

Comment: In order to confirm your current issue, can you provide the sample URL for testing your script?

Comment: @Cooper, thanks for your reply. I cant manipulate the feed. Or should I modify the script and ask for the "rss" element? But there is no element named "rss" in the feed.

Comment: Hey @Tanaike, thanks for your reply! Thats actally your script I was trying to modify :D 
I added the RSS feed URL as well a link to your solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modified script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function SAMPLE(url, n = 1) {
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var root = XmlService.parse(res.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")).getRootElement();
  var ns = root.getNamespace();
  var entries = root.getChildren("entry", ns);
  if (!entries || entries.length == 0) return "No values";
  var header = ["id", "title", "link", "updated", "content"];
  var values = header.map(f => f == "link" ? entries[n - 1].getChild(f, ns).getAttribute("href").getValue().trim() : entries[n - 1].getChild(f, ns).getValue().trim());
  return [values];
}
```

- In this case, when you use `getChild` and `getChildren`, please use the name space. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.
- From your script, I guessed that you might use your script as the custom function. In that case, please modify the function name from `ImportFeed` to others, because `IMPORTFEED` is a built-in function of Google Spreadsheet. In this sample, `SAMPLE` is used.
- If you want to change the columns, please modify `header`.
- In this sample, the default value of `n` is `1`. In this case, the 1st entry is retrieved.
- In this script, for example, you can put `=SAMPLE("URL", 1)` to a cell as the custom function. By this, the result value is returned.

#### Note:

- If the above-modified script was not the direct solution of your issue, can you provide the sample value of `res`? By this, I would like to modify the script.
- As the additional information, when you want to put all values by executing the script with the script editor, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function myFunction() {
      var url = "###"; // Please set URL.

      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      var root = XmlService.parse(res.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")).getRootElement();
      var ns = root.getNamespace();
      var entries = root.getChildren("entry", ns);
      if (!entries || entries.length == 0) return "No values";
      var header = ["id", "title", "link", "updated", "content"];
      var values = entries.map(e => header.map(f => f == "link" ? e.getChild(f, ns).getAttribute("href").getValue().trim() : e.getChild(f, ns).getValue().trim()));

      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name.
      sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Hi There @Tanaike, thank you very much for your help! I opened a new Google Apps Script and called the function "SAMPLE("RSS-URL", 10)" from a Google Spreadsheet. I got me a response indeed!
Is there a way I can use "n" as a limiter and not as a selector? It would be great to have the first "n" rss-feed-entries, not "numer n" only. I'm sorry - this was not clear from my description!

Comment: Wow! Works now: I can call and write the complete RSS feed to Spreadsheet. 
Awesome, thanks a lot @Tanaike!

Comment: I came over one thing @tanaike, i had to change this 
````var root = XmlService.parse(res.replace(/&/g, "&amp;")).getRootElement();````
to
````var root = XmlService.parse(res).getRootElement();````

becaus I need the URLs without the modification. I did not see problems resulting from this modification.